# Mobile browser chrome doesn't go away when scrolling using Polymer's core-header-panel

Tags: css, polymer, dart-polymer

In most mobile sites, scrolling will hide Safari's header and footer chrome.

However, when using Polymer's `core-header-panel` or `core-scroll-header-panel`, the chrome is always present.

(EDIT: Related issues on GitHub: https://github.com/Polymer/core-scroll-header-panel/issues/19, https://github.com/Polymer/core-header-panel/issues/15)

Here's a Facebook screenshot, and notice how the chrome goes away as I scroll down:

[image: Facebook]

Here's a screenshot of my Polymer app, and notice how the chrome remains:

[image: Polymer app]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polymer's core-scroll-header-panel with submenu toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026247/polymers-core-scroll-header-panel-with-submenu-toolbar)